# How to extend /dev/sda1 disk space from 28 Gb to 60GB

Tags: server, partitioning

I haven't done this before. It is an ubuntu server. I have checked other answers but I am not that confident to follow. I am confused with /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda5 as they have the same size but different types. Ideally I would like to shrink this 382G space and give it to /dev/sda1.

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048  58593279  58591232   28G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        58593280 175779839 117186560 55.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       175781886 976771071 800989186  382G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       175781888 976771071 800989184  382G 83 Linux
```

I have increased sda1 successfully

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ1Pb.jpg)

[Can't allocate the 1MB unallocated space?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv5hf.jpg)

Comment: Boot Ubuntu desktop from a live USB. Use gparted.

Comment: Check if your Ubuntu version really needs a swap partition. (Not if it is a recent version.) If so, leave some space for it and create one.

Comment: @user68186 It is a server, does not have user interface to use gparted only commands. parted in command line is lack of file system functions thats what I read.

Comment: @Jos not sure if it needs a swap partition, it is 16.04

Comment: That's why I suggested boot from USB Ubuntu desktop. The ISO comes with gparted.

Comment: You have to download the desktop ISO from Ubuntu site. Create a bootable USB, called live USB. Boot from the USB. Choose "Try Ubuntu without installing" option to run the desktop version from the USB. Open gparted...

Comment: You cannot resize the server partition while it is running. It is like trying to change a tire of your car while you are driving it.

Comment: @user68186 thank you for your clear suggestions, I get your points now, cheers

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of gparted and add it to the question?

Comment: Yeah, will do once I get to that point.

Comment: if you don't have GUI then it's better to use [a TUI partitioner](https://askubuntu.com/q/105542/253474)

Comment: @phuclv looks like it works with unallocated space, can't shrink a partition?

Comment: @user68186 I have attached the screenshots for resized the partitions, somehow I can't allocate the 1MB unallocated space do you know why?

Comment: New partitions begin at the beginning of a block. Sometimes that means 1MB is left in between partitions. You can't do anything about it.