# Are there some Text User Interface programs for ffmpeg and other?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, ncurses

`fdisk` seems to have a [Text User Interface via Cfdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105542/text-user-interface-for-fdisk).

But I would like to know if there are some other useful tools like this for, let's say: `ffmpeg` and maybe some other like mail clients, other than alpine and these not-so-easy to use for the common user.

I mean: something easier, something which looks like a program, made for using the program, not to code it from scratch and without the need to write complex commands to do the task.

In example: If I want to convert my `png` files to `jpg` in a folder I know I can run `for i in *.png; do convert "$i" -[parameter1] -[parameter2] -[parameter3] -[and so on] converted-"$i".jpg; done;`

What if there is a tool for text mode only which shows something like this?

```
------------------------------
Folder [ ~/Pictures/folder-to-convert/ ]

Source Format      [ PNG ]
Destination Format [ JPG ]

[X] Resize
--- Width  [ 1920 ] [ ] auto
--- Height [      ] [X] auto

[X] Change quality
--- Percentage [ 60 ]

          [ PROCESS ]
------------------------------
```

Maybe something like this has been made before, and for other tasks. Which I would like to find.

## Edit

Here is an example of what I am looking for, but for other software, like ffmpeg and if there is a collection of Software like this, I'll appreciate your answers.

### LazyGit

In example, Jesse Duffield has created `lazygit`

> A simple terminal UI for git commands, written in Go with the gocui
>   library.
>   Source: https://github.com/jesseduffield/lazygit

Which, in my laptop looks like this:

[image]

And this animation, which is provided by Jesse Duffield git repository:

[image]

I know I can create my own piece of Software with `python`, `php`, or any other programming language. But I would like to find alternatives to some GUI's for the terminal only.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That's AKA the 'curses' interface which requires adding the [ncurses library](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/ncurses.3ncurses.html) with

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

Each curses interface app has its own package. One example is [cmus](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cmus-plugin-ffmpeg) ([more](https://www.tecmint.com/install-cmus-music-player-in-linux/)) for ffmpeg.

You can web search for more with the search term *nameofapp curses ncurses* . Once you find one, then confirm it's available for your version number of Ubuntu with `man nameofapp` run at a shell prompt.

Comment: So far I haven't been able to find something useful when looking for `ffmpeg curses ncurses`. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I knew about `cmus` before and it seems to be a terminal music player, not an interface to use `ffmpeg` (other than playing music, of course). Please give me your guidance if I am misunderstanding your answer. I appreciate your help and efforts.